# Correct C Syntax for Function moved to RAM

Tags: function, pointers

I have a function that resides in flash memory but must run from ram.

Since it is not used often, I do not want the linker to relocate it.

Every thing is relative addressing so I can move it my self.

I'm using gcc for ARM and can't get the syntax correct in assigning the ram location to the ram based function pointer - please help

This is the function in flash:

byte Flash_Function(byte)
{
 ... code
}

These are global RAM variables

// pointer to ram based function .. called from flash based routines

byte (*Ram_Based_Routine)(byte) = 0;  // issue is assigning a value to this

// XXX holds enought space to have routine copied into it

byte Ram_PlaceHolder_For_Function[XXX];

There is a function that does moves the function "Flash_Function" into the array "Ram_PlaceHolder_For_Function" and initializes Ram_Based_Routine pointer

I can't get syntax correct on this assignment line

Ram_Based_Routine = (*Flash_Function(byte))(Ram_PlaceHolder_For_Function);

if I were assigning the flash function -- this would be fine
Ram_Based_Routine = &Flash_Function;

So -- how to cast Ram_PlaceHolder_For_Function into Flash_Function?

Thanks for any comments

Comment: Type type of a pointer to your routine is `byte(*)(byte)` so your cast should use that type `(byte(*)(byte))Ram_Placeholder`

Comment: THAT was the solution - Thanks